# Plotting a list of "Numerical" functions

Tags: plotting, evaluation, warning-messages

In expressions like

```
Plot[Through@{# &, #^2 &}@x, {x, -1, 1}]
```

`Plot` effectively interprets the first argument as a vector-valued function, and plots both lines in the same colour:

[image]

To make `Plot` interpret the first argument as a list of functions, we need to wrap the argument in `Evaluate`, as in

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through@{# &, #^2 &}@x, {x, -1, 1}]
```

yielding

[image]

But what if the list of functions is a list of `PredictorFunction` objects, each of which expects a numeric, or "Numerical", argument?

```
predictors = Predict[{1 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> -1, 4 -> 0}, Method -> #] &
    /@ {"DecisionTree", "GaussianProcess"};
Plot[Evaluate@Through@predictors@x, {x, 0, 5}]
```

This yields the desired plot

[image]

but with `PredictorFunction::mlincfttp` errors. Is there a way of doing this without generating the errors and without using `Quiet` to suppress them? I need to pass the predictors as a list just like `predictors`; there are too many to write out explicitly in the first argument to `Plot`, as in `{p1[x], p2[x], ...}`; I need a programmatic solution.

Comment: If you cannot suppress the warning message, by wrapping your whole code in `Quiet[]`, perhaps you can use `Off[PredictorFunction::mlincfttp]` before the code is executed. Would that work?

Comment: It would work, thanks @MichaelE2. But I'm really looking for something which doesn't generate any errors and therefore doesn't have to suppress them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `Off[PredictorFunction::mlincfttp]` won't work, perhaps this:

```
(* holds up evaluation until x is numeric *)
ClearAll[applyN];
applyN[f_][x_?NumericQ] := f[x];

Plot[Evaluate@Through@(applyN /@ predictors)@x, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You could try with:

```
Show[Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]] & /@ 
  predictors]
```

Or if you want the same colorscheme for each plot:

```
colors = {Blue, Red};
Show[Plot[predictors[[#]][x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> colors[[#]]] & /@
   Range@Length[predictors],PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image]

Comment: The `{x, 0, 1}` should be `{x, 0, 5}` to reproduce the plot shown in the image.

Comment: true, I forgot to change it back